# Use of "as" keyword in vbscript

Tags: vbscript

I am new to this stackoverflow programming community and new to vbscript.I just need to know the use of "as" keyword in vbscript. For eg :

```
Dim something: set something = "i am cool" as string
```

I just need to know the use of as keyword here.I know there are many keywords like integer and many more .If any one have any idea please help me ..Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no `AS` in `VBScript`. In VBScript, variables are always of one fundamental data type, Variant.

Refer: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t7zd6etz%28v=vs.84%29.aspx

I think you are confusing `VBA` with `VBScript`

Comment: are you damn sure its not for vb script ? Then.can you tell me the use of as in vba ?

Comment: @user3138386 When in doubt, read the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f8tbc79x%28v=vs.84%29). VBscript doesn't have a keyword `As`, so you most definitely have not seen it being used in any working VBScript. Are you perhaps confusing it with the [`Is`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ake1y5wx%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) operator?

Comment: Visual Basic has `AS`, doesn't it? 
Be careful because VBScript, Visual Basic, and VBA are all different things.

Answer (score 0):

**As** is only the reserved keyword in VBScript, but it is actually not used, because VBScript treats all variables 1 type, the variant. There is no need to define the type in VBScript.

Source: https://isvbscriptdead.com/reserved-keywords/